# How to Import Images into Anki While Keeping LaTeX Functionality?

Tags: latex, anki

I setup Anki with LaTeX following this guide here: http://www.hyperbolics.caths.cam.ac.uk/links/latexankisetup.php

Basically, I changed the front template to:

```
.card {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 10px;
text-align: center;
color: black;
background-color: white;
}
img {
width: auto;
height: auto;
max-height:1000px;
}
```

and the Back template to:

```
[latex]{{Front}}[/latex]

<br /><br />
<hr id=answer>
<br />

[latex]{{Back}}[/latex]
```

Next, I installed MiKTeX, as suggested by the ankisrs guide here: http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#latex-support

Here is a basic example of the cards I can create: [image]

The inputs for this card for the front and back respectively are `Kinetic Energy` and `$\Delta KE = \frac{1}{2} m\Delta (v^2)$`. (The front/back templates I copied from the first link allows regular text, like on the front card in this example, to appear "*Tex-like*" without writing it as `$\text{Kinetic Energy}$`)

However, issues occur when I attempt to import an image. If I drag and drop it into Anki to get something like this (the blocked out sidebar is just my other decks): [image]

But when I (pre)view it, the image doesn't appear, and I get something like this: [image]

So, the question is: **how do I import images while keeping LaTeX functionality?** If I get rid of all the modifications suggested by the two links above, images work fine by dragging and dropping. But once LaTeX modifications are added, importing images no longer works.

Comment: I'm very interested in the answer myself.
I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903732/how-to-insert-an-image-into-anki-notes-in-latex-format) is related.

Comment: I don't understand why the answer to that question was downvoted, the official docs seem to say you should put the [latex] tag around the actual LaTeX within your fields and never wrap a field with a media or LaTeX. http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#media-&-latex-references

Answer (score 3):

The problem is LaTeX won't directly understand the image data passed to it.

You could instead either use the `[latex][/latex]` tags in the actual field content (and click and drag your image after it), removing the `[latex][/latex]` tags from your template, like so:

[image: Card with LaTeX tags in fields]

[image: Template with LaTeX tags removed]

Or if typing those unneccessary `[latex][/latex]` tags seems tedious, you can create an additional field (by clicking the "Fields..." button) for Images, and move the `{{Image}}` field out of the  `[latex][/latex]` tags in the template:

[image: Card with Image field]

[image: Template with Image outside of LaTeX tags]

Check [The Anki Manual](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html) for tricks you can do with fields (including conditional rendering).

Comment: I don't wanna be rude, but this is just the obvious non-answer. The bounty was created to solve the problem at hand (ie: publish pictures within Latex, with all its associated functionalities), not to quote the official alternatives.

Comment: @Sovos Thanks for your comment, and I don't find it rude. I've only recently started trying to answer SO questions, so it's good to hear constructive criticism.

I respectfully disagree that this is an obvious non-answer however. The OP states "how do I import images while keeping LaTeX functionality? If I get rid of all the modifications suggested by the two links above, images work fine by dragging and dropping. But once LaTeX modifications are added, importing images no longer works." The solution allows the OP to import images while keeping LaTeX functionality.

Comment: @Sovos To elaborate slightly, it seems that the OP's only stated problem was that the image they dragged didn't render. It didn't seem to me that they specifically wanted LaTeX's image functionality because they didn't appear to be trying to use that in their demonstration. The OP could also use LaTeX to render the images, but without drag and drop support. Syncing is also non-trivial when the images are in separate files, so I ignored that alternative (it could be another question in and of itself).